# No me muestra correctamente el mensaje de error en Mysql5.7

Tags: mysql

en el mysql5.1 si hay algún error en la sintaxis me muestra la ayuda correspondiente con una descripción clara, pero después de instalar el mysql5.7 ya no pude observar ese detalle. Me gustaría saber si es normal este comportamiento del 5.7 o es un bug. Gracias[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnB1P.png)

Comment: Esta pregunta no esta ciertamente relacionada a programación, me parece que tu duda es porque en la versión 5.7 no se agrega toda la descripción del error. En realidad no creo que sea un problema para nosotros como desarrolladores ya que simplemente buscamos en la documentación el código de error para tener la definición del mismo.

Comment: Que tal... sería una consulta a ustedes, para saber si es normal ese comportamiento del mysql, o yo instalé/configuré algo mal...

Comment: Y se que no repercute mayor dificultad al desarrollador, debido que el código de error se puede usar para buscar una solución, pero en este caso es sólo una consulta mía si esto es normal o no. Gracias

Comment: Tendrías que detallar exactamente la herramienta que usas para efectuar la consulta y las etapas que seguistes para obtener el error.  Porque yo uso MySQL 5.7 también, pero yo obtengo todos los detalles del error correctamente.

Comment: Entonces puede ser un bug de mi instalación, me podrías dar la versión exacta de tu mysql o su instalador?, el mio es "mysql-installer-community-5.7.20.0.msi". Y tanto con el gestor heidysql o desde la terminal de windows me muestra lo mismo.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es una pregunta sobre programación

Comment: Para mi es un problema de programación ya que si aparece un error como desconocido en la pantalla de una aplicación en producción al usuario se le hace mucho más difícil comunicar del problema y a nosotros también para interpretar de inmediato porque necesitamos acceder a la documentación (se pierde tiempo buscando el mensaje de error), es mucho más comodo ver la leyenda detallada. Desde mi punto de vista la pregunta es útil y estaré a la expectativa de una solución a este inconveniente. Saludos!